# How to convert all audio formats to mp3 in php?

Tags: php, audio, mp3, formats

How to convert all audio formats to mp3 in php

Comment: PHP is a scripting language. Why people choose to abuse it in this way, I will never know or understand.

Comment: Its possible using PHP by using ffmpeg extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ffmpeg can be helpful. For details http://ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 1):

at first you install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) on your system. (it is free), then in PHP you can call the ffmpeg to convert any audio file to mp3 using the system command like this:

```
<?php
$output = system("ffmpeg parameters...");
echo $output;
?>
```

see the ffmpeg documentation for examples how to call ffmpeg.