# Convert SND/AU to mp3 using PHP

Tags: php, audio, mp3

Is it possible to convert a .au audio file to mp3 file using PHP ?
How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results. [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I have not write any code. I ask you if it's possible for this. I thought the question was clear, i'm looking for an implementation of this

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are also off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using ffmpeg can be helpful. For details http://ffmpeg.org/

from: [How to convert all audio formats to mp3 in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840650/how-to-convert-all-audio-formats-to-mp3-in-php)
Please, use google search first.